# HTTP Request with Airflow PythonOperator

Tags: python, macos, airflow

I'm trying to run a dag with Python Operator as followed. Every time I manually run this dag, airflow scheduler stops. So the run looks like running forever.

When I directly run `utils.get_rate()` in a python script without dag, it always works. I only have an issue when I run it in dag. Simplifying the operator to just print something works.

```py
from Exchange_Rate import utils
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
import datetime

default_args = {
'owner': 'admin',
'email':"****@gmail.com"
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id="exchange-rate-to-line",    
    schedule="0 18 * * *",
    start_date=datetime.datetime(2023, 7, 15),
    catchup=False,
    default_args=default_args,
)


task = PythonOperator(
        task_id=f'exchange_rate_to_line',
        python_callable= utils.get_rate,
        dag=dag
    )
```

The Dag log stops when trying to send HTTP requests until I kill the task.

```
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID='exchange-rate-to-line' AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID='exchange_rate_to_line' AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE='2023-07-29T12:21:56.333954+00:00' AIRFLOW_CTX_TRY_NUMBER='1' AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID='manual__2023-07-29T12:21:56.333954+00:00'
[2023-07-29T13:22:00.084+0100] {utils.py:23} INFO - Getting exchange rate API key...
[2023-07-29T13:22:00.089+0100] {utils.py:42} INFO - Sending HTTP request to exchange rate API...
```

When I newly run airflow scheduler, I got this airflow scheduler log.

```
[2023-07-29 13:25:45 +0100] [73796] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2023-07-29 13:25:45 +0100] [73796] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('::', 8793)
[2023-07-29 13:25:45 +0100] [73796] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2023-07-29T13:25:46.326+0100] {settings.py:60} INFO - Configured default timezone Timezone('Europe/London')
[2023-07-29T13:25:46.345+0100] {manager.py:411} WARNING - Because we cannot use more than 1 thread (parsing_processes = 2) when using sqlite. So we set parallelism to 1.
[2023-07-29 13:25:46 +0100] [73796] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('::', 8793)
[2023-07-29 13:25:46 +0100] [73796] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2023-07-29 13:25:47 +0100] [73796] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('::', 8793)
[2023-07-29 13:25:47 +0100] [73796] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2023-07-29 13:25:48 +0100] [73796] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('::', 8793)
[2023-07-29 13:25:48 +0100] [73796] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2023-07-29 13:25:49 +0100] [73796] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('::', 8793)
[2023-07-29 13:25:49 +0100] [73796] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2023-07-29T13:25:50.338+0100] {dagrun.py:609} ERROR - Marking run <DagRun exchange-rate-to-line @ 2023-07-29 12:21:56.333954+00:00: manual__2023-07-29T12:21:56.333954+00:00, state:running, queued_at: 2023-07-29 12:21:56.352181+00:00. externally triggered: True> failed
[2023-07-29T13:25:50.339+0100] {dagrun.py:681} INFO - DagRun Finished: dag_id=exchange-rate-to-line, execution_date=2023-07-29 12:21:56.333954+00:00, run_id=manual__2023-07-29T12:21:56.333954+00:00, run_start_date=2023-07-29 12:21:57.108894+00:00, run_end_date=2023-07-29 12:25:50.339046+00:00, run_duration=233.230152, state=failed, external_trigger=True, run_type=manual, data_interval_start=2023-07-27 17:00:00+00:00, data_interval_end=2023-07-28 17:00:00+00:00, dag_hash=5321608c331baa96d84ddc8b0af4ee7d
[2023-07-29T13:25:50.349+0100] {dag.py:3504} INFO - Setting next_dagrun for exchange-rate-to-line to 2023-07-28T17:00:00+00:00, run_after=2023-07-29T17:00:00+00:00
[2023-07-29 13:25:50 +0100] [73796] [ERROR] Can't connect to ('::', 8793)
```

`get_rate()` comes from the following utils.py.
When I just ran `get_api_key()` in dag for test, it returned the correct value, so this function should be fine.

```py
import requests
import os
import json
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from datetime import date
import logging

# Logging setting
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(20)
fhandler = logging.FileHandler(filename=r'main.log')
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(message)s')

load_dotenv()

def get_api_key():

    """
    Get api key of ExchangeRate-API
    """

    try:
        logging.info('Getting exchange rate API key...')
        api_key = os.environ['EXCHANGE_RATE_API_KEY']
        return api_key
    except KeyError:
        logging.error('Key Error in get_api_key(). Check the environmental variable EXCHANGE_RATE_API_KEY.')
        raise
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f'Error in get_api_key(). {type(e)} : {e}')
        raise

def get_rate():

    """
    Get JPY exchange rate of 1 GBP
    """
    api_key = get_api_key()
    req = f'https://v6.exchangerate-api.com/v6/{api_key}/latest/GBP'

    try:
        logging.info('Sending HTTP request to exchange rate API...')
        response = requests.get(req, timeout = 10)
        jpy = response.json()['conversion_rates']['JPY']
        return jpy
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f'Error in get_rate(). {type(e)} : {e}')
        raise
```

I'm running airflow on a virtual environment in my local machine.

Mac OS with M1 /
Airflow 2.6.3

Comment: do you see any log in the task ? can u understand what is the last command that ran ?

Comment: also, I wouldn't return a string in get_rate exception, its better to throw error so the task would fail

Comment: Thank you for your advice. 
I've added logger, and put the log.

Comment: check if you have 2 schedulers that run, cause the error that you see suggest that the port already in use. BTW your code is running succesfully in my mac so its a matter of airflow infra and not the dag itself

Comment: can you check that the environment variable `EXCHANGE_RATE_API_KEY` actually exists on the machine running airflow?

Comment: A friend of mine tried with the same environment, and he had the same issue.
And I tried it with Ubuntu remote server, and it worked. I think there's something wrong with Mac M1 airflow.